# Finding an $x$ that satisfies the Jacobsthal function for the primorial of the $n$th prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, primorial, integer-sequences

The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences has a nice [page](https://oeis.org/A048670) on the gaps found related to the [Jacobsthal function for primorials](https://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function).

I would like to take a look at the sequences that have these gaps shown in this [list](https://oeis.org/A048670/list).  Using a brute force algorithm, I was able to find the the start of $n=9$ the gap for $23\#$ which starts at $20332472$.

I have an algorithm which can quickly find gaps of length $2(p_{n-1}+1)+2$ which works for $n=1$ thru $n=8$ and also includes $n=10, 11, 13$.

Is there a list in oeis that lists the start of these gaps?  I was not able to find it.
If not, does anyone know of such a list?  I would be very interested in seeing the patterns that can be found in these sequences of consecutive integers.

Comment: Is https://oeis.org/A049300 what you want?

Comment: Yes, thanks @GerryMyerson!  I suspected it was there but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list, up to $24$, is given at https://oeis.org/A049300/b049300.txt
Here it is:
$$
\matrix
{1& 2\hfill\cr
2 &2\hfill\cr
3& 2\hfill\cr
4& 2\hfill\cr
5 &114\hfill\cr
6 &9440\hfill\cr
7 &217128\hfill\cr
8 &60044\hfill\cr
9& 20332472\hfill\cr
10& 417086648\hfill\cr
11& 74959204292\hfill\cr
12 &187219155594\hfill\cr
13 &79622514581574\hfill\cr
14 &14478292443584\hfill\cr
15 &6002108856728918\hfill\cr
16 &12288083384384462\hfill\cr
17 &5814429911995661690\hfill\cr
18 &14719192159220252523420\hfill\cr
19 &7714600835154917969172\hfill\cr
20 &396499427735806558888610\hfill\cr
21 &3084626641924131277081102880\hfill\cr
22 &77624949518856340312883476188\hfill\cr
23 &23314635458774315797705662793622\hfill\cr
24 &990578949024486399796411481983580\hfill\cr}
$$